# JavaScript: unable to assign value without alert

Tags: jquery, json, alert, assign

I have declared this function in .js file and calling it in .html file.

```
function getTotalPages() {
    var valuePage;
    $.getJSON('Data/product.json').
        done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                valuePage=value;
            });
        });
    //alert('out');
    return valuePage;
}
```

The above function returns the "undefined" without "alert", with alert it is working good. Can any one help me on this.

Thank you
In advance.

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been answered a thousand times. It's about 'there is no way to return any value from an asynchronous request'. Everything you want to do with `valuePage` you should do inside the `done` callback.

Comment: Thank you, now I am doing with call back, is there any way to assign the value to other variable?

Comment: You can assign the value to any variable you want ... why not, where is the problem?

Comment: I am assigning the variable in the callBack, but unable to get the value out of the callBack function. it is showing "undefined".

Comment: You can access it after(!) the callback finished. Because of the asynchronous nature of Ajax requests you cannot assume that the code after the callback will run after the callback, because it just doesn't. It will run before(!) the callback so the variable will still be undefined. But if you access the variable (e.g. with a button click) after the callback finished, it will be defined!

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because your ajax request is asynchronous. 
With alert you have a timeout after which the value is returned. You can make your script work  by adding `async: false` **(note for cross-domain requests using `jsonp` you cannot make synchronous request!)** but actually I don't recommend you because your JS will block until the request is ready. Better approach is to use a callback:

```
function getTotalPages(callback) {
  var valuePage;
    $.getJSON('Data/product.json').
        done(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(value);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is an example how you can do this using asynchronous request:

```
function getResult(callback) {
    var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=mgechev&count=3';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(data);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
}

getResult(function (data) {
    var variable = data;
    alert(variable);
});​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vWnHJ/

In the example I pass function to the `getResult` function and call the given function with the data received from the request.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous, by the time you close the alert message the returned value will be resolved, but without the alert it would be too early. You can either make a synchronous request or use a callback.